# Is a "property" some kind of "instance variable" in Objective-C or are they different?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is there much of a difference between "property" and an "instance variable" in Objective-C?

I have been led to believe that an instance variable that has accessor methods is knows as a "property", but I now I think that this might not be true.

Comment: Fast. That answers my question perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance variable is unique to a class. By default, only the class and subclasses can access it. Therefore, as a fundamental principal of object-oriented programming, instance variables (ivars) are private—they are encapsulated by the class.

By contrast, a property is a public value that may or may not correspond to an instance variable. If you want to make an ivar public, you'd probably make a corresponding property.

There is a [nice blog](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/should-i-use-a-property-or-an-instance-variable/) to go through. Also, go through the link shared by katleta300 above.